# How to correctly rotate irregular rectangle with OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to rotate an irregular rectangle like this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POD0y.png)

With the purpose of placing it straight. My contour is a cv::vector< cv::Point > type and after the transformation I get a cv::vector< cv::Point2f > type, in order to make some calculations with fine precission.

Because of that, I also need a good way of making this rotation, so first I need to detect the sides. I've tried to use 'minarearect' but the result is not fine at all. The bounding rectangle does not match the irregular rectangle orientation with the enought precission.

Is there any 'best perimeter rectangle' or similar, instead of the 'minimal area rectangle'? I think it would give me more accuracy.
However, do you know any other method for rotating the rectangle?

Excuse my english. And thank you for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PCA to get sides for rectangle orientations (1-st and second components), having these axes directions you can compute rotation angle. Example here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/dee/tutorial_introduction_to_pca.html

[image]

Just made a sketch of another variant:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void getSamplePoints(Mat& src,vector<Point2f>& pts)
{
    pts.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < src.rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < src.cols; ++j)
        {
            uchar v = src.at<uchar>(i, j);
            if (v > 0)
            {
                pts.push_back(Point2f(j, i));
            }
        }
    }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
double distance_to_Line(cv::Point2f line_start, cv::Point2f line_end, cv::Point2f point)
{
    double normalLength = _hypot(line_end.x - line_start.x, line_end.y - line_start.y);
    double distance = (double)((point.x - line_start.x) * (line_end.y - line_start.y) - (point.y - line_start.y) * (line_end.x - line_start.x)) / normalLength;
    return distance;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void getPointsFromVector(vector<Point2f>& pts,Point2f p1, Point2f p2, float dist, vector<Point2f>& pts_res)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pts.size(); ++i)
    {
        double d = distance_to_Line(p1, p2, pts[i]);
        if (fabs(d) < dist)
        {
            pts_res.push_back(pts[i]);
        }
    }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, unsigned int** argv)
{
    string fname = "../../data/rect_to_fit.png";
    Mat src = imread(fname, 1);
    if (src.empty())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    cvtColor(src, src, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    vector<Point2f> pts;
    getSamplePoints(src, pts);


    RotatedRect R = minAreaRect(pts);
    Point2f r_pts[4];
    R.points(r_pts);

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        vector<Point2f> res_pts;
        Point2f p1 = r_pts[j];
        Point2f p2 = r_pts[(j + 1) % 4];
        getPointsFromVector(pts,p1,p2,20, res_pts);
        for (auto p : res_pts)
        {
            circle(src, p, 3, Scalar::all(255), -1);
        }
      //  imshow("src", src);
      //  waitKey(0);
        Vec4f L;
        fitLine(res_pts, L, cv::DIST_L2, 0, 0.01, 0.01);
        float x = L[2];
        float y = L[3];
        float vx = L[0];
        float vy = L[1];
        float lefty = int((-x*vy / vx) + y);
        float righty = int(((src.cols - x)*vy / vx) + y);
        line(src, Point2f(src.cols - 1, righty), Point2f(0, lefty), Scalar::all(255), 2);
    }

    imshow("src", src);
    imwrite("result.jpg", src);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

The result I got:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying first with PCA. As soon I get my first results, I'll give you feedback!

Comment: PCA gives directions of longest distibutions of points, in case of square it may give diagonals directions.  PCA will work good for recangles or other elongated objects. For square like ones you may need to use RANSAC approach.

Comment: PCA is not giving me any good approach, as you can see here: [example](http://i68.tinypic.com/2cs72bt.png). I think it's also a bad approaching to the diagonals...

Comment: Appended my sketch that solves it better. It search lines of sides, and you can find rotation from it (by averaging angle of parallel sides for ex).

Comment: Wow, that's great! Thanks a lot, Andrey!